# Disable outlook email editor

Tags: outlook, modal-dialog, addin-express

I am working on an Outllok adding built with Add-in Express. I am trying to show a modal progress dialog which blocks only the current mail composer/editor window, so that user can still use Outlook while this dialog is shown, but he should not be able to edit the current email. I tried using

```
dialog.ShowDialog(new WindowWrapper(ADXAddinModule.CurrentInstance.GetOutlookWindowHandle(mail.GetInspector)));
```

but it blocks whole Outlook. `WindowWrapper` is just a simple class implementing `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window`. Is there a way to achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanisms for that. A dialog window should be closed before coming back to other windows because Outlook windows are not standalone applications, they all represent a single application - MDI.

As a workaround you can use the `Show` method of the Form class instead. In that case you will be able to move focus to any window in Outlook. To block only the current mail composer/editor window (so-called inspector) you can handle the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865363.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Inspector class which is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code. So, in the event handle you can bring the windows form to front for preventing any changes in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that. I am also considering using sth else than a modal dialog. Would it be possible to "inject" a kind of control/panel into the inspector (where I could show some progress status etc.) and at the same time disable the inspector?

Comment: can you elaborate on how to actually handle Activate event? I have an instance of MailItem, I call mailItem.GetInspector and gett a COM object, can't seem to attach event handlers on it.